# Pandas: Converting part of a row into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Apple, eggs, pineapple pizza', 'orange, soda, pepsi, cola', 'pear, watermelon, pizza, lasagna', 'apple, eggs, human sandwich, human chili'], columns=['A'])

                                          A
0              Apple, eggs, pineapple pizza
1                 orange, soda, pepsi, cola
2          pear, watermelon, pizza, lasagna
3  apple, eggs, human sandwich, human chili
```

What I want to output is this:

```
['apple, eggs, pineapple, pizza', 'orange, soda, pepsi, cola', 'pear, watermelon, pizza, lasagna', 'apple, eggs, human sandwich, human chili']
```

I am not sure where to begin, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
df2.A.values.tolist()
Out[412]: 
['Apple, eggs, pineapple pizza',
 'orange, soda, pepsi, cola',
 'pear, watermelon, pizza, lasagna',
 'apple, eggs, human sandwich, human chili']
```

Comment: you may possibly be my favorite SO person for all the help you always provide. This is perfect. Thank you.